# How do I retrieve the contents of Document Set in Sharepoint by querying JSON?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint document library containing a document set. Inside the document set I've stored 5 files: 2 .jpg files, 2 .docx files and a .txt file. How can I retrieve the names of all these files using the ID of the document set using a JSON query?

So far I haven't been able to find a method that can achieve the outcome I'm looking for.

Comment: Please update the question with the SharePoint version and any code that you have tried (even if not working).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following api to get all file name in library

```
$.ajax({
            url: "site.url/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('LibraryName')/items?$select=FileLeafRef",
            type: "GET",
            headers:
                       {
                           "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                       },
            success: filesuccess,
            error: error
        });
```